# interact with tmux pane as if it were a vim buffer

Tags: vim, tmux

I use tmux and vim quite a bit.

One thing I have always wanted to be able to do, but have not find a way for, is to be able to interact with a tmux pane as if it were a vim buffer. I do not know if this is even possible (?).

Basically, what I would like is:

- 1 do some work in tmux
- 2 use a tmux shortcut
- 3 now my tmux should act like vim, in particular to be able to navigate, copy, paste

The closes I can get to 2) and 3) is to use Ctrl-B + [ , which lets me navigate my tmux history, but:

- I cannot use the usual vim navigation, I have to use arrows
- I cannot easily for example yank text, etc

Any idea if 1) this is doable, 2) how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few tweaks you can apply to your `.tmux.conf` to make tmux feel a little more at home for a vim user.

### Navigation

To switch tmux panes using `hjkl` navigation as in vim, add this to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key h select-pane -L
bind-key j select-pane -D
bind-key k select-pane -U
bind-key l select-pane -R
```

With this, you can use e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> to select the pane to the left.

### Copy, Search, Select

tmux has a built-in vi-mode for copy mode. Enable it via

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

in your `.tmux.conf`.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> to enter copy mode. With `vi` mode enabled, you can now use `hjkl`-style navigation to move your cursor around, search forward and backward using `/` and `?` respectively.

To make copying and pasting feel more at home, add these two lines to your `.tmux.conf` to enable `v` as a shortcut for text selection (similar to vi's visual mode) and `y` as a shortcut for copying/yanking selected text:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

You can use `p` to paste text, this is standard in `vi` mode in tmux.

Comment: Many thanks :) I knew about the tricks in the Navigation section, but not the ones in the Copy Search Select :)

Comment: I let opened a bit more to see if I get other answers and then I accept :) .